# Create new Z-Score column based off unique text values in an existing column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, pandas-groupby, transform

**System:** O365

**IDE:** JupyterLab

**Language:** Python version 3.7.3

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**Data source:** personally built

**Http API Documentation:** https://github.com/RTICWDT/open-data-maker/blob/master/API.md

Hello, I am wondering if anyone knows how to return a value utilizing a conditional setting within a column range. For instance, I would like to return z-scores based on like values within a range changing once the next group of values is seen.

**Steps were taken:**

1. built the below function it seems to be halfway there but not quite so

**Code:**

```
# get data
df0 = pd.read_csv('data/erpservicedesk.csv')
df0.columns

# put z-score into a lamda
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()

# build datafram with the important features
df1 = df0[['Incident ID*+', 'Res.Prod.Cat.TierII', 'Res.Op.Cat.TierIII', 'Mean-Time-Tckt-Close']]

df1.insert(4,'ZofMTTC',df1.groupby(['Res.Prod.Cat.TierII', 'Res.Op.Cat.TierIII'])['Mean-Time-Tckt-Close'].transform(zscore))

df2 = df1.sort_values(by=['Res.Prod.Cat.TierII'])
df2.head(100)
```

**Problem**

It appears my lambda function is not conditional based on new column values as it seems to take the 'Mean-Time-Tckt-Close' for the entire dataframe rather than each new instance of 'Res.Prod.Cat.TierII'.

**Example**

```
A B C
Bob Store 10
Bob Store 11
Bob Store 8
Alfred Store 12
Alfred Store 9
```

I need a new column D to reflect the Z-Score for Bob and Alfred based off their respective data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your example, you can create dfs to store the mean and standard deviation using `.groupby`, then access these in a lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd

## recreate example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Bob']*3+['Alfred']*2, 'B':['Store']*5, 'C':[10,11,8,12,9]})

df_mean =  df.groupby('A').mean()
df_std =  df.groupby('A').std()

## apply the function along each row, using axis=1
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['C'] - df_mean.loc[x['A']]) / df_std.loc[x['A']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        A      B   C         D
0     Bob  Store  10  0.218218
1     Bob  Store  11  0.872872
2     Bob  Store   8 -1.091089
3  Alfred  Store  12  0.707107
4  Alfred  Store   9 -0.707107
```

Comment: This method works beautifully. However, I noticed I started getting errors like this when trying to add on Columns to data frame slices: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" Do you understand why this is I read the documentation and it appears like pandas essentially want you to either add on to the original data frame or create an entirely new one.

Comment: This happens when you're working with dataframe slices but it is ambiguous whether you want to modify the slice of the original df, and happens when you use chained assignment. For example: `df[df['some_column']== 10]['some_other_column'] = 1000` will throw that error.